# Can I use ''exist'' predicate in the definition of algebra in equationally definable class?

Tags: universal-algebra

I'm reading *Algebraic Theories* by Ernest G. Manes,

and I'm wondering about **equationally-definable** class.

For example, *group* is a typical example of equationally-definable algebra,

but the definition of *group* uses ''for-all'' sentence: $\forall x,y,z\in X.\;x\cdot(y\cdot z)=(x\cdot y)\cdot z$;

thus I'm curious that whether can I use $\forall$, $\exists$, etc. in definition of equationally-definable algebra.

Comment: As far as I know, "$\forall x \in X, \exists y \in Y$ such that..." is a very common mathematical sentence.

Comment: No. Equationally definable classes can only be axiomatized by universally quantified equations.

Comment: @MarcoRipà Yes, but "equationally-definable" is a very strict condition **not** allowing existential quantifiers (or even disjunctions).

Comment: Despite the presence of the words "algebraic" and "theory," the "algebraic-k-theory" tag is irrelevant; I've replaced it with a more relevant one. Separately, this question would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you! I'm sorry since I am new to mathoverflow and didn't find any relevant tag....